# Forest app like feature where it detects you've left the app

Tags: ios, swift, ios12

I'm looking for a way in swift with iOS 12 to detect if the user has left the app the way the forest app does. So far I've looked everywhere but haven't found a way to do this. The main issue is that I can't figure out if the user has left the app by going to another app or by locking the phone. I have seen some hacky solutions to this, but I would like a more genuine solution.

I was wondering if the I could distinguish by checking the screen brightness as the func applicationDidEnterBackground is called, and if it's 0, it would mean that the screen was turned off. Not sure if the screen turns off before function is called however.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just curious what you intend to do when the user leaves the app.

Comment: Just to send a local notification. It's for a productivity app.

Comment: Are you searching for State Restoration continue app from where user quit or stopped  ? https://www.raywenderlich.com/1395-state-restoration-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: no just need to know how the user leaves the app.